How to change font size in i3wm config?
I've recently migrated from linuxmint to archlinux using typecraft's excellent video series but I'm having issues using i3-wm. I simply want to increase the font size in i3's config but I'm not able to update the current setting. Even when the font size is increased, restarting the config using mod+shift+r does nothing. I've copied /etc/i3/config into ~/.config/i3/config but I'm still unable to change the config file.
If I do make changes to the config file then try to go back into it I get thrown'E325: ATTENTION' followed by 'Found a swap file by the name'...
The i3 config is the default, as follows...
# i3 config file (v4)
#
# Please see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html for a complete reference!
#
# This config file uses keycodes (bindsym) and was written for the QWERTY
# layout.
#
# To get a config file with the same key positions, but for your current
# layout, use the i3-config-wizard
#

# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
font pango:monospace 8

# This font is widely installed, provides lots of unicode glyphs, right-to-left
# text rendering and scalability on retina/hidpi displays (thanks to pango).
#font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 8

# Start XDG autostart .desktop files using dex. See also
# https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Autostart
exec --no-startup-id dex --autostart --environment i3

# The combination of xss-lock, nm-applet and pactl is a popular choice, so
# they are included here as an example. Modify as you see fit.

# xss-lock grabs a logind suspend inhibit lock and will use i3lock to lock the
# screen before suspend. Use loginctl lock-session to lock your screen.
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock --nofork

# NetworkManager is the most popular way to manage wireless networks on Linux,
# and nm-applet is a desktop environment-independent system tray GUI for it.
exec --no-startup-id nm-applet

# Use pactl to adjust volume in PulseAudio.
set $refresh_i3status killall -SIGUSR1 i3status
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +10% && $refresh_i3status
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -10% && $refresh_i3status
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle && $refresh_i3status
bindsym XF86AudioMicMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ toggle && $refresh_i3status

# use these keys for focus, movement, and resize directions when reaching for
# the arrows is not convenient
set $up l
set $down k
set $left j
set $right semicolon

# use Mouse+Mod1 to drag floating windows to their wanted position
floating_modifier Mod1

# move tiling windows via drag & drop by left-clicking into the title bar,
# or left-clicking anywhere into the window while holding the floating modifier.
tiling_drag modifier titlebar

# start a terminal
bindsym Mod1+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal

# kill focused window
bindsym Mod1+Shift+q kill

# start dmenu (a program launcher)
bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id dmenu_run
# A more modern dmenu replacement is rofi:
# bindsym Mod1+d exec "rofi -modi drun,run -show drun"
# There also is i3-dmenu-desktop which only displays applications shipping a
# .desktop file. It is a wrapper around dmenu, so you need that installed.
# bindsym Mod1+d exec --no-startup-id i3-dmenu-desktop

# change focus
bindsym Mod1+$left focus left
bindsym Mod1+$down focus down
bindsym Mod1+$up focus up
bindsym Mod1+$right focus right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Left focus left
bindsym Mod1+Down focus down
bindsym Mod1+Up focus up
bindsym Mod1+Right focus right

# move focused window
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$left move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$down move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$up move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+$right move right

# alternatively, you can use the cursor keys:
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Left move left
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Down move down
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Up move up
bindsym Mod1+Shift+Right move right

# split in horizontal orientation
bindsym Mod1+h split h

# split in vertical orientation
bindsym Mod1+v split v

# enter fullscreen mode for the focused container
bindsym Mod1+f fullscreen toggle

# change container layout (stacked, tabbed, toggle split)
bindsym Mod1+s layout stacking
bindsym Mod1+w layout tabbed
bindsym Mod1+e layout toggle split

# toggle tiling / floating
bindsym Mod1+Shift+space floating toggle

# change focus between tiling / floating windows
bindsym Mod1+space focus mode_toggle

# focus the parent container
bindsym Mod1+a focus parent

# focus the child container
#bindsym Mod1+d focus child

# move the currently focused window to the scratchpad
bindsym Mod1+Shift+minus move scratchpad

# Show the next scratchpad window or hide the focused scratchpad window.
# If there are multiple scratchpad windows, this command cycles through them.
bindsym Mod1+minus scratchpad show

# Define names for default workspaces for which we configure key bindings later on.
# We use variables to avoid repeating the names in multiple places.
set $ws1 "1"
set $ws2 "2"
set $ws3 "3"
set $ws4 "4"
set $ws5 "5"
set $ws6 "6"
set $ws7 "7"
set $ws8 "8"
set $ws9 "9"
set $ws10 "10"

# switch to workspace
bindsym Mod1+1 workspace number $ws1
bindsym Mod1+2 workspace number $ws2
bindsym Mod1+3 workspace number $ws3
bindsym Mod1+4 workspace number $ws4
bindsym Mod1+5 workspace number $ws5
bindsym Mod1+6 workspace number $ws6
bindsym Mod1+7 workspace number $ws7
bindsym Mod1+8 workspace number $ws8
bindsym Mod1+9 workspace number $ws9
bindsym Mod1+0 workspace number $ws10

# move focused container to workspace
bindsym Mod1+Shift+1 move container to workspace number $ws1
bindsym Mod1+Shift+2 move container to workspace number $ws2
bindsym Mod1+Shift+3 move container to workspace number $ws3
bindsym Mod1+Shift+4 move container to workspace number $ws4
bindsym Mod1+Shift+5 move container to workspace number $ws5
bindsym Mod1+Shift+6 move container to workspace number $ws6
bindsym Mod1+Shift+7 move container to workspace number $ws7
bindsym Mod1+Shift+8 move container to workspace number $ws8
bindsym Mod1+Shift+9 move container to workspace number $ws9
bindsym Mod1+Shift+0 move container to workspace number $ws10

# reload the configuration file
bindsym Mod1+Shift+c reload
# restart i3 inplace (preserves your layout/session, can be used to upgrade i3)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+r restart
# exit i3 (logs you out of your X session)
bindsym Mod1+Shift+e exec "i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'You pressed the exit shortcut. Do you really want to exit i3? This will end your X session.' -B 'Yes, exit i3' 'i3-msg exit'"

# resize window (you can also use the mouse for that)
mode "resize" {
        # These bindings trigger as soon as you enter the resize mode

        # Pressing left will shrink the window’s width.
        # Pressing right will grow the window’s width.
        # Pressing up will shrink the window’s height.
        # Pressing down will grow the window’s height.
        bindsym $left       resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $down       resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $up         resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym $right      resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # same bindings, but for the arrow keys
        bindsym Left        resize shrink width 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Down        resize grow height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Up          resize shrink height 10 px or 10 ppt
        bindsym Right       resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt

        # back to normal: Enter or Escape or Mod1+r
        bindsym Return mode "default"
        bindsym Escape mode "default"
        bindsym Mod1+r mode "default"
}

bindsym Mod1+r mode "resize"

# Start i3bar to display a workspace bar (plus the system information i3status
# finds out, if available)
bar {
        status_command i3status
}

#######################################################################
# automatically start i3-config-wizard to offer the user to create a
# keysym-based config which used their favorite modifier (alt or windows)
#
# i3-config-wizard will not launch if there already is a config file
# in ~/.config/i3/config (or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/i3/config if set) or
# ~/.i3/config.
#
# Please remove the following exec line:
#######################################################################
exec i3-config-wizard

Any help is much appreciated! Again, bit of a newbie so apologies if this is a very stupid question.


thrown'E325: ATTENTION' followed by 'Found a swap file by the name'

Navigate to ~/.config/i3/ and put in your terminal ls -lah. You will see a hidden file called .config.swp or something like that. Remove that file and you will be able to edit the config file.

To increase the fontsize in window titles and in the i3status bar. Search the following lines in the config file:

# Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
# is used in the bar {} block below.
font pango:monospace 8

and then modify that number 8 as you want.
Finally press mod+shift+r to apply the changes.
